# Why does my application crash every time I try to show two child view controllers that are GLKViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller

Example project: http://d.pr/f/v7zD

I'm trying to build an app that would show two `GLKViewController`s. I'm using Storyboards, so I have my main view controller (the initial one) with two container views in it that branch off into two UIViewControllers that have a custom class of `OpenGLViewController` (which is just a subclass of `GLKViewController` I've created).

The views within those two child view controllers are `GLKView`s.

Yet, every time I run it I get this error as soon as it launches:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[GLKViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but didn't get a GLKView.'

How do I make this work? I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: I managed to get it working. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is your view `IB` outlet correctly set?

It can be that your `GLKViewController` subclass, is not able to find the expected outlet to a `GLKView`.

I managed to fix your project. You can download it [here](http://d.pr/f/JZ69). Basically, the view outlets were incorrectly set and the initial view controller class was wrongly set in `IB`. I also set the delegates. Check out the screenshots.

[image]

[image]
Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have any outlets set at the moment. Could you check out the linked project?